# How to change this batch command to use only selected folders?

Tags: windows, batch-file

The code below moves all files under each movie folder into the appropriate movie folder, and if there are empty folders they'll be deleted.
Example:
Before:
D:\MOVIES
-----------\Bikini Spring Break
-------------------------------\EPCSKGCWZCXDJEH
------------------------------------------------------------\DVD
-----------------------------------------------------------------\P2HBSB5.iso
-----------------------------------------------------------------\0001.jpg
-----------------------------------------------------------------\lees.txt

After:
D:\MOVIES
------------\Bikini Spring Break
----------------------------------\P2HBSB5.iso
----------------------------------\0001.jpg
----------------------------------\lees.txt

```
@echo off
 pushd "d:\MOVIES"
    for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir /ad /b ') do (
       pushd "%%a"
         for /r %%b in (*) do move /-y "%%b" . 
         for /f "delims=" %%c in (' dir /b /s /ad ^|sort /r') do rd "%%c" 2>nul
       popd
    )
 popd
```

Is it possible to change something in the code from this batch command so only in selected folders the code is executed?

Maybe it's just a minor change if this batch command is placed into the "MOVIES" folder and executed from there.
Example:
If from these three movies only "Bikini Spring Break" and "Static" are selected in the "MOVIES" folder, I want only the code executed on these movies.

D:\MOVIES\Bikini Spring Break
---------------\Breaking the Girls
---------------\Static

Comment: How are you selecting the folders?  Drag and drop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work for you -

It uses drag and drop to process the folders that are selected.
Drag the folders onto the batch file.

What it doesn't do is check for filename clashes if any exist when moving the files recursively into a movie folder.

It is untested so make some copies of your folders and test it first.

```
@echo off
:loop
       pushd "%~1"
           for /r %%b in (*) do move "%%b" .
           for /d %%c in (*) do rd /s /q "%%c"
       popd
       shift
       if not "%~1"=="" goto :loop
```

Comment: It didn't work. It deletes all subfolders and all that's in it.       
But the idea to drag the selected folders to the bat is good, otherwise it isn't possible to start the bat if folders are selected.

Comment: I had a `%%a` where it should have been `%%b` - test it now.  NOTE that if a folder has a name like `one&two` then it will fail due to a bug in explorer drag and drop where it is not quoted.  The problem character is `&` where there are no `spaces` in the name as well.

Comment: This seems to work on a test folder. Now I'm going to test it on multiple folders. But I don't know what "d:\movies" is doing in the code. The folders are dragged into the bat. Why is there a folder assigned in the code?

Comment: And is there a limitation for the bat to execute it on several folders? I wanted to test it on 174 folders but it doesn't do anything. If I drag two folders it does work.

Comment: You're right about the unneeded folder - I started this with a different type of script and it just stayed in there - so I removed those lines.  A command line can only be 8 KB long in XP and later I think, so 174 paths are probably going to exceed that.  You may have to do it in a few bites.